# Generate a migration for adding a foreign key (table name with 2 words)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table named product_categories. And I wanna create an self-relationship. What is the right way to do it using migrations generate command? I did this and it didnt work:
**rails g migration AddProductCategoryToProductCategories productcategory:references**

Comment: You will have to use an underscore `product_category` or something like that

Comment: Thar worked. Thanks!

Comment: Have a read through this, very helpful on migrations http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Comment: and this too maybe, http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html. Good luck

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just to summarize what worked in the comment section.
You must use

```
product_category
```

instead of

```
productcategory
```

Rails uses `_` as a separator between names, called snake case. This can all be a little bit confusing when beginning to use Rails, and indeed even after using Rails for a long time. The guides are your friend...

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score -1):

Generally speaking, the table name can be whatever you want it to be. I for one sometimes find Rails naming conventions a bit whacky.

If you've already generated the product_categories and products models/ tables, then just do:

```
rails generate model product_categories_products product_id:integer product_category_id:integer
```

This will generate a model that stores both foreign keys and acts as a proxy table.

You would then need to set up Product model with:

```
has_many product_categories_products
has_many product_categories, through: product_categories_products
```

Then define the following in ProductCategory

```
has_many product_categories_products
has_many products, through: product_categories_products
```

And Finally in ProductCategoryProduct

```
belongs_to product
belongs_to product_category
```

However, the above naming convention is horrible. You'd be better off renaming ProductCategory to just 'Category' and then your proxy table model can be 'ProductCategory'.

...or you could renaming it something completely different and then just manually specify the class_name in the association definitions.

Comment: Thanks @JayJay. The thing is that I have 2 categories tables on my database. So I really dont know how to name both and at the same time respect the naming convetion of rails.